# Can I use android:width, android:height and android:viewportWidth, android:viewportHeight when I want to draw a png bitmap?

Tags: android, xml

I created the following xml file from an .svg vector file in Android Studio:

ic_cercle.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="288dp"
    android:height="288dp"
    android:viewportWidth="76.2"
    android:viewportHeight="76.2">
  <path
      android:pathData="M38.1,38.1m-25.1354,0a25.1354,25.1354 0,1 1,50.2708 0a25.1354,25.1354 0,1 1,-50.2708 0"
      android:strokeWidth="0.529167"
      android:fillColor="#ff0000"
      android:strokeColor="#000000"/>
</vector>
```

Then, I use it here in my project:

ic_myimage.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_background" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cercle"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

Now, I want to draw the same image as bitmap image instead of vector. I have added a 288x288dp png file(ic_cercle_png) to my project.

How can I draw a 288x288dp bitmap image instead of the vector image?

I have created this xml file but I don't know if I can add android:width="288dp", android:height="288dp", android:viewportWidth="76.2" and android:viewportHeight="76.2" to ic_myimage_png.xml.

ic_myimage_png.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/color_background"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cercle_png"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Can I use android:width, android:height and android:viewportWidth, android:viewportHeight when I want to draw a bitmap in the center of the screen?

What is android:viewportWidth and android:viewportHeight? Should I use them when I draw a bitmap image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with bitmap pictures in the  element, you do not require the android:width, android:height, android:viewportWidth, and android:viewportHeight properties.

Android:viewportWidth and android:viewportHeight are used to scale and position vector graphics in vector drawables by defining the vector drawable's coordinate system. Bitmap pictures are not compatible with these properties.

The android:gravity="center" attribute that you have in your ic_myimage_png.xml file should be adequate if your aim is to center the bitmap image. If necessary, change the bitmap's size in the ic_cercle_png source file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to the combination of wrap_content for the android:layout_height of the XYPlot and the android:weightSum attribute in the parent LinearLayout. The wrap_content height might not work well with the weight calculation in certain cases.

To ensure that each XYPlot takes 50% of the screen height, you can try setting the android:layout_height of both XYPlot elements to 0dp and the android:layout_weight of their parent LinearLayout elements to 1. This should distribute the available height equally between the two plots.

Here's the modified XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF003B"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
            android:id="@+id/pawGraph"
            style="@style/APDefacto.Light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:rangeTitle="Pressure (cmH2O)"
            app:graphMarginBottom="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFE600"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
            android:id="@+id/tidalVolume"
            style="@style/APDefacto.Light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:graphMarginBottom="0dp"
            app:lineLabelTextSizeBottom="0dp"
            app:rangeTitle="Tidal Volume" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't help me. I want to know if I can use android:width, android:height and android:viewportWidth, android:viewportHeight when I want to draw a bitmap in the center of the screen?

And what is android:viewportWidth and android:viewportHeight? Should I use them when I draw a bitmap image?